# @PostUpdate and @PostPersist cause infinite loop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is some action that needs to be done after an entity is persisted in the database. And that action again needs to call the database in order to fetch some entities.

In order to perform the action, I am using the annotations `@PostUpdate` and `@PostPersist`.
So my entity class looks like,

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    // some class fields
    // some methods

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    public void performActionAfterPersist() {

        someService.performSomeAction(id);

    }
}
```

The class SomeService looks like this:

```
public class SomeService {

    // some class fields
    // some methods

    public void performSomeAction(int id) {

        MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(id);
        // some other stuff done on myEntity

    }
}
```

As soon as the `findById` method is called, it again goes back to the method annotated with `@PostUpdate` and `@PostPersist`.

Could anyone please tell me why this is happening and how it can be fixed? Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: Me too facing the same issue, did you got the resolution please ?

Comment: No. I just stopped calling the findById in the same thread. I made these two calls asynchronous.